# Magento 2 : on main sever We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this email

Tags: magento2, cms-pages

my code is running perfectly on local host but when i am uploading on server after running its showing

> This above error We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating
>   this email.

my block code show.php is

```
<?php
namespace Diaspark\Location\Block;

class PageLink extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    protected $_locationFactory;
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Diaspark\Location\Model\locationFactory $db)
    {
        $this->_locationFactory = $db;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getDisplayData()
    {

        $data=$this->_locationFactory->create()->getCollection();

        return $data;
    }
     public function getImagePath()
    {
       $imagePath = $this->_storeManager->getStore()
                    ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
       $var= $imagePath .'mycustomfolder/';
       return $var;

    }

}
```

and PHTML code is

```
<?php
$_gridrecords = $block->getDisplayData();

foreach ($_gridrecords as $d ) 
{   $id= $d->getEntityId();

    echo " ".$id;
}

?>
```

on cms page is calling my block like this way

```
{{block class="Diaspark\Location\Block\Show" template="show.phtml"}}
```

> location.php in model

```
<?php

/**
 * Auction Location Model.
 *
 * @category    Diaspark
 *
 * @author      Diaspark Software Private Limited
 */
namespace Diaspark\Location\Model;

use Diaspark\Location\Api\Data\LocationInterface;

class Location extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel implements LocationInterface
{
    /**
     * CMS page cache tag.
     */
    const CACHE_TAG = 'diaspark_location';

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_cacheTag = 'diaspark_location';

    /**
     * Prefix of model events names.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'diaspark_location';

    /**
     * Initialize resource model.
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Diaspark\Location\Model\ResourceModel\Location');
    }
    /**
     * Get EntityId.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getEntityId()
    {
        return $this->getData(self::ENTITY_ID);
    }

    /**
     * Set EntityId.
     */
    public function setEntityId($entityId)
    {
        return $this->setData(self::ENTITY_ID, $entityId);
    }

    /**
     * Get Title.
     *
     * @return varchar
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->getData(self::TITLE);
    }

    /**
     * Set Title.
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        return $this->setData(self::TITLE, $title);
    }


    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->getData(self::IMAGE);
    }

    /**
     * Set image
     * @param string $image
     * 
     */
    public function setImage($image)
    {
        return $this->setData(self::IMAGE, $image);
    }


    /**
     * Get getContentFirst.
     *
     * @return varchar
     */



    /**
     * Get IsActive.
     *
     * @return varchar
     */
    public function getLocationDescription()
    {
        return $this->getData(self::LOCATION);
    }

    /**
     * Set PublishDate.
     */
    public function setLocationDescription($location_description)
    {
        return $this->setData(self::LOCATION, $location_description);
    }



     public function getAddress()
    {
        return $this->getData(self::ADDRESS);
    }

    /**
     * Set PublishDate.
     */
    public function setAddress($address)
    {
        return $this->setData(self::ADDRESS, $address);
    }

    public function getContact()
    {
        return $this->getData(self::CONTACT);
    }

    /**
     * Set PublishDate.
     */
    public function setContact($contact)
    {
        return $this->setData(self::CONTACT, $contact);
    }

  public function getPublishDate()
    {
        return $this->getData(self::PUBLISH_DATE);
    }

    /**
     * Set PublishDate.
     */
    public function setPublishDate($publishDate)
    {
        return $this->setData(self::PUBLISH_DATE, $publishDate);
    }
}
```

any  help will be appreciated please
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

protected $_filesystem;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $_filesystem,
)
{
    $this->_filesystem = $_filesystem;
}
```

You can get media path by using below code:

```
$imagePath = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath();
$var = $imagePath .'mycustomfolder/';
return $var;
```

The solution you used will return you URL path not Folder Path.

Comment: actually  getImagePath is runing fine but getDisplayData is not running

Comment: can you please add the code of `\Diaspark\Location\Model\locationFactory`